# Proofs involving sequential limit

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $S$ be the domain of the function $f$. Suppose $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\Bbb N\right\}$. Show $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L$ iff  $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=L$.

Idea: I want to say, let $S$ be defined as above and take $x_n:=\frac{1}{n}$. Then it follows that $<x_n> \to 0$ iff $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now we elected $S$ to be the domain of $f$ so, if we assume $<x_n> \to 0$ then $f\left(x_n\right) \to L$ for some real number $L$. Thus, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x_n|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L$ iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=L.$

Comment: Can I get a hint on how to start this because that didn't really get me going? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = L$, then given $\varepsilon >0$, for all sufficiently small $x$, $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. Then, of course $|f(1/n) - L| < \varepsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Conversely, given $\varepsilon >0$, if $\lim_n f(1/n) = L$, then for all sufficiently large $n$, $|f(1/n) - L| < \varepsilon$. Since, the function is defined on $S=\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ for all sufficiently small $x$ and $x \in S$, which is the definition of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) =L$.